# I have created a .rdlc-Report under VS 2012 using the report i want to assign data source and report name at run time

Tags: c#, rdlc, dynamic-rdlc-generation

I have many reports for my project and I have just a report Viewer and want to open all the reports in this viewer, for this viewer data source is assigned at run time and report name also

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();

DataTable dt = new DataTable();              

using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("R_PURCHASE_ORDER_DETAIL", parent.v_connection))
{
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("START_CODE", SqlDbType.VarChar)).Value = "0000000000";
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("END_CODE", SqlDbType.VarChar)).Value = "9999999999";
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    da.Fill(ds);
}
reportViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = @"E:\BusinessBook\BusinessBook\BusinessBook\ZReports\Purchase\r_purchase_order_detail.rdlc";

ReportDataSource datasource = new ReportDataSource("R_PURCHASE_ORDER_DETAIL", ds.Tables[0]);

this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(datasource);
reportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();
reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

Comment: And what is your problem, getting an exception or what?

Comment: Do you mean you want to open multiple report in one report viewer?